# Can't enter text in a textarea

Tags: html, css, forms

I cannot enter text in the message section. It will not let me click and type. The name, email and anti-spam sections work fine, only the textarea doesn't. I've googled and found no solution in regards to HTML textarea tag.

```
<form method="post" action="email.php">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

    //this is the problem 
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
    <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.contact-form input[type=text],
.contact-form input[type=password],
.contact-form input[type=email],
.contact-form textarea,
.contact-form input[type=file] {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    border: 1px #DFDFDF solid;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.contact-form textarea {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    resize: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L27ykzd/1/)

Comment: I guess that message field is 'covered up' with another element.... your css is problem... post it, please

Comment: It works for me, http://geekfellows.com/works.jpg  check this http://jsfiddle.net/bom8jygq/

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6L27ykzd/

Comment: Maybe something in JS

Comment: there's nothing wrong with css

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6L27ykzd/1/

Comment: Your fiddle works fine

Comment: It doesn't work fine.  I can't enter text in the textarea.

Comment: Check this http://geekfellows.com/works1.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have:

```
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea { 
color: inherit;
font: inherit;
margin: 0px;
}
```

The problem is `font: inherit;` which use `line-height: 0px` from `form` element. So set `line-height: 1.2em` to `textarea` or other value as you wish.

Comment: i'm with the same problem, but that didn't fix it. any other solution?